# Visual studio 2010 consume webservice in windows application (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to consume a web service in windows application
but I am having some challenges.
I did that by right clicking on **References** -> **Add Service Reference** -> **Advance** -> **Add web Reference** .
When I enter the url of the webservice (http://server/webserviceName?wsdl), it rather opens the file download dialog box asking me to save or cancel , so I am not able to proceed.
Please any ideas? Kindly see screen shots

[image: Error from VS2010]

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked.It was a Java web service.
I added the ServiceModel as part of the references.
References -> Add Reference -> ServiceModel (under the .Net tab)